# Get the host of the URL

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am made an API that works as it is intended, but to stop the direct use of the base URL of the API, there is another URL that masks the base URL but works the same.

I need to return the URL that is masking the base URL for pagination, but when I write
 `Request.Host` I get the base URL, which should not be revealed.

```
A = https://baseurl.com/api
B = https://publicurl.com/api

B masks A
need to return B for pagination in the response.

Just need to get https://publicurl.com and not the whole url.
```

How can I get the URL(just the Host) of the one that is masking the base URL?

Comment: Where are you writing `Request.Host` from? A, B, a third app that is using A, a third a app that is using B?

Comment: I am writing ```Request.Host``` in the controller class, A is hosted on Azure, and B is masking that URL, and B will be used for all the requests like GET, POST.

Comment: In the controller class of which app?

Comment: @eduherminio the controller class of the API I am working on.